# how to add multiple markers to mapview in android?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-mapview

I am working on android **geolocation** application in that I have added marker for current location and want to add markers for other geopoints also. I have created objects of `OverlayItem` for other points and adding it to `ItemizedOverlay` like `itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem)` and then adding it to `mapOverlay.add(itemizedOverlay)`. For the current location `geopoints` getting from **"Location"** object and other points are hard-coded values. After executing it only current location marker is displayed not the other hardcoded points.
How can I add marker for these `geopoints` and where?

Thanks ,
Vishakha.

Comment: can you post your code vishakha ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme